# Flutter: Awesome Notification Choose Sound from storage

Tags: flutter, localnotification, flutter-notification

I am using flutter awesome notification and I want user can choose custom sound from their storage. Is it possible to make it?
Here is my code to initialize the awesome notification plugin.

```
AwesomeNotifications().initialize(
  'resource://drawable/logo',
  [
    NotificationChannel(
      channelKey: 'alarm_notification',
      channelName: 'alarm_notification',
      channelDescription: 'Notification channel for alarm',
      defaultColor: Color(0xFFFFDA2B),
      ledColor: Colors.white,
      vibrationPattern: highVibrationPattern,
      soundSource: 'resource://raw/slow_spring_board',
      importance: NotificationImportance.Max,
    )
  ]
);
```

and this is my acode to create notification

```
AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
  content: NotificationContent(
    id: alarmId,
    channelKey: 'alarm_notification',
    title: alarmTitle,
    body: alarmBody,
    displayOnBackground: true,
    displayOnForeground: true,
    customSound: "string",
  ),
  schedule: NotificationCalendar(
    hour: alarmTime.hour,
    minute: alarmTime.minute,
    second: 0,
    millisecond: 0,
    timeZone: "Asia/Jakarta",
    repeats: true,
  )
);
```

Comment: Did you manage to get that to work?  I can't even get it to work with static customSound. I tried in the initialize with soundSource: 'resource://raw/zedd'   and also in the createNotification with customSound: 'asset://assets/audio/zedd.mp3',   I get no errors. it just ignores my custom sound :(

Comment: @J-L in the end I didn't use the custom sound selectable from storage. I made a dropdown of the sound options that I provide. on AwesomeNotifications initialization I create multiple NotificationChannels with different soundSources. make sure you save the audio file in /android/app/src/main/res/raw/your_file.mp3. and in your raw folder create a keep.xml file which includes your audio files. then i also don't add customSound on NotificationContent

Comment: Thanks for the info about the keep.xml I had no idea about that file. Unfortunately still doesn't work for me .. did you have to add any special permission in the AndroidManifest?  for now I have :
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY"/>

Comment: ok got it to work now..  I had to completely remove the app from the phone .. before running , I think the channels for the notifications were messed up from testing so much ..

Answer (score 1):

According to the [plugin documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_notifications#-media-source-types) Sounds can only be resource files meaning they can only be predefined by the developer and cannot be chosen by user as you want.

---

[image]

---

So the only possible option is as you mentioned in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69827321/flutter-awesome-notification-choose-sound-from-storage#comment133532447_69827321) to load many sounds in `res` and allow users to choose from them.